# Make a probability distribution from two distributions in Julia

Tags: julia

```
using Distributions
d1 = Exponential(0.2)
d2 = Exponential(0.5)
p = 0.7
```

Is there any easy way I construct a distribution in Julia, that behaves like a distribution in that I can call `rand()` and `rand!`, that behaves as follows:  draw from distribution `d1` with probability `p` and draw from distribution `d2` with probability `1-p`. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a [`MixtureModel`](https://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/latest/mixture.html):

```
julia> m = MixtureModel([d1,d2],[p,1-p])
MixtureModel{Distributions.Exponential{Float64}}(K = 2)
components[1] (prior = 0.7000): Distributions.Exponential{Float64}(θ=0.2)
components[2] (prior = 0.3000): Distributions.Exponential{Float64}(θ=0.5)

julia> mean(m)
0.29000000000000004

julia> pdf(m, 0)
4.1

julia> rand(m)
0.2574516697519676

julia> rand!(m, zeros(1,5))
1×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0704624  0.264519  0.636179  0.11479  0.41158
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. This solution works better. There was a good chance something like this was baked into the Distributions package. Now I'll remember it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution.

Comment: If I wanted one of the distributions to return its value times -1 (as if I was making a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), how would I do that? It does not like `MixtureModel([d1, -d2],[p,1-p])`

Comment: @BenS. If you use my version, then negating `d2` is simple, just put it into the `rand` function. In fact, any transformation of the outputs is possible (time to return the check to my answer ;)? In a transformed function, the extra functionality of MixtureModel is not useful (the mean and density aren't correct).

Comment: @Matt regarding MixtureModel, it doesn't implement `cdf` which is a shame, since it is possible (and easy) to calculate the CDF. But Stack Overflow comments are no place for issues/feature-requests or pull requests.

Comment: @BenS. There is a [Laplace distribution](https://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/latest/univariate.html#Distributions.Laplace) builtin, too, but I'm guessing you want something that's not symmetric.

Comment: @DanGetz thanks I will do that! jeez now I don't know what to do about marking only one as the answer...

Comment: @BenS. Ah.. this is the better answer! Keep it marked.

Answer (score 2):

`Distributions.jl` basically prepared all the tools to define new distributions. So, in this case, my attempt looks like:

```
using Distributions

struct CompoundBernoulli{T<:Distributions.VariateForm,
                         S<:Distributions.ValueSupport} <:
         Distributions.Sampleable{T, S}
    p::Bernoulli
    d1::Distributions.Sampleable{T,S}
    d2::Distributions.Sampleable{T,S}
end

# outer constructor  
CompoundBernoulli(p::Real, 
                  d1::Distributions.Sampleable{S, T},
                  d2::Distributions.Sampleable{S, T}) where 
  {S<:Distributions.VariateForm, T<:Distributions.ValueSupport} = 
  CompoundBernoulli{S,T}(Bernoulli(p),d1,d2)

Base.rand(cb::CompoundBernoulli) = rand(cb.p)==0 ? rand(cb.d1) : rand(cb.d2)
```

With these definitions:

```
julia> cb = CompoundBernoulli(0.7,Exponential(0.2),Exponential(0.5))
CompoundBernoulli{Distributions.Univariate,Distributions.Continuous}
(Distributions.Bernoulli{Float64}(p=0.7), 
Distributions.Exponential{Float64}(θ=0.2), 
Distributions.Exponential{Float64}(θ=0.5))

julia> rand(cb)
0.3247418465183849

julia> rand(cb,3,3)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.33105   0.231418  0.271571
 0.413905  0.662144  1.42725 
 0.20196   0.091628  0.194761
```

More functions can be defined and functions can be specialized for this specific type as the application requires.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Bravo for rolling your version so quickly.  It's actually very close to how the builtin `MixtureModel` is defined!  They just use a Categorical distribution instead of Bernoulli so it can support mixtures of more than two components.